# Check if object declared const

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I would like to break the compilation if the object is declared const.

The following doesn't work :

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {

    A() : v(0)
    {
        static_assert( ! std::is_const<decltype(*this)>::value, "declared as const" );
    }

    int& AccessValue() const
    {
        return const_cast< int& >( v );
    }

    int v;
};

int main()
{
    A a1; // ok, this compiles
    const A a2; // no, this break the compilation

    a1.AccessValue() = 5; // ok
    a2.AccessValue() = 6; // OPS
}
```

So, is there a way to break the compilation if an object of this type is declared const?

Comment: I doubt it is possible. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: If someone gets a `const A` but shouldn't, the compiler will eventually give errors basically saying the same thing (declared as const), so you don't really need to check for such things.

Comment: @AlexandreC. It is UB to use const_cast to change from const reference to non-const reference, unless the object is declared non-const. I need to use const_cast, but would like to prevent people from declaring objects of this type const.

Comment: @VJovic If that were possible I guess compilers would already check it, since that’s a very useful and obvious diagnostic to do before `const_cast`.

Comment: @VJovic: You should probably redirect your efforts to avoid the need of `const_cast`. That is, the better questions are: Why do you **need** `const_cast`? How can you **avoid** using `const_cast`?

Comment: I modified my example to demonstrate what I mean. Instead of int, it should be some complex class. If you think it's not possible, then it should be an answer, no?

Comment: @VJovic: wouldn't making `i` mutable achieve what you want without the cast?

Comment: @Mat I am not sure if changing the value using the `AccessTheValue()` method is UB or not. EDIT : Found it [dcl.type.cv]/4 says it is ok to modify method variable declared as mutable. Thanks

Comment: @VJovic: as `Mat` said, it is not UB if `i` is `mutable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are heading the wrong way.

The type of `this` is purely dictacted by the signature of the method in which you use it. That is, `this` is always of type `cv T* const` where `cv` corresponds to the CV qualifiers of the method.

Therefore, in a constructor, `this` is just `T* const`.

---

`const_cast` is a code smell, normally only of use when dealing with `const`-broken legacy libraries... or (sometimes) to avoid violating DRY. In new code, you should not have to use it.

You are left with a choice:

- make `AccessValue` non-const, since it is not
- declare `i` as being `mutable`.

I would advise choosing the former solution. Giving away a handle to a `private` attribute is bad already (breaks encapsulation), no need to violate `const` correctness as well.

Comment: `this` is never `U const`. It is an rvalue. `const` doesn't make sense for non-object rvalues, so there are no non-class/non-array rvalues of that type

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: this, I guess, it the legalese approach. In practice [it is qualified](http://ideone.com/Gzgyg). Perhaps because this helps the compiler diagnosing ill-formed calls ? (avoiding the addition of extraneous logic for `this`)

Comment: if you pass "this" to a template and deduce its type and gcc deduces it as "U const" you not only have a confusing diagnostic (btw, a diagnostic that says "this" has type "U const" doesnt mean that it really has that type) but an actual bug. Some compilers also talk about expressions that have type "U &" when they wanna tell the user that it is an lvalue of type "U".

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: so should we considered there is a bug in [gcc 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/NWpyr) and [gcc 4.5.2](http://ideone.com/BCNWP) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Yes, all those should print "none". Compiler should implement `this` by substituting it with `(__this + 0)`, where `__this` is the actual `this` value. The `+ 0` makes it an rvalue. (Johannes showed me this idea.)

Comment: @GManNickG: I think I actually misinterpreted Johannes' comment (I tend to do that a lot). It makes sense for `this` to point to `const` or `volatile` objects, what does not make sense is for `this` itself to be `const`. And my examples never covered this case. Apparently, gcc (at least) correctly treats it as an rvalue: http://ideone.com/qfs7h

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Oh, and I even misread your tests. Well I'm glad we're both clear now. :)

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, making `i` mutable would achieve your goal:

```
int& AccessValue() const
{
    return v;
}

mutable int v;
```

This is from §7.1.6.1/4 [dcl.type.cv]:

> **Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified**, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

Note that you can't modify `v` using a pointer-to-member on a const object - §5.5/5 of n3290 draft [expr.mptr.oper]:

> [ Note: it is not possible to use a pointer to member that refers to a mutable member to modify a const class object. For example,

```
struct S {
S() : i(0) { }
mutable int i;
};

void f()
{
const S cs;
int S::* pm = &S::i; // pm refers to mutable member S::i
cs.*pm = 88;         // ill-formed: cs is a const object
}
```

> — end note ]

Comment: But I don't have pointer to member variable. Therefore [7.1.6.1/5, latest c++11] applies, there it is allowed to change it. There is even an example

Comment: Yes, the mutable member works. I was just pointing out that there are some things you can't do even though the member is mutable - using a pointer to member specifically. But as long as you don't do that it is good.

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple variables referring to the same object, some mutable and some const.
For example:

```
A a1;
const A &a2 = a1;
A * const pa = &a1;
f(a1);
....
void f(const A &a);
```

should these be allowed in your case?
Conversion from mutable to const is implicit the reverse is not. 
Maybe if you give an example will help.

EDIT: (in response to modified code)
with a const object you can call only const member function.
why not have:

```
int& AccessValue()
{
    return v;
}
```

an the compiler with complain if you call AccessValue on a non const object.

Comment: Modified my example. Hope it is better now