# Can an object know its own constness?

Tags: c++, reflection, c++11, type-traits, const-correctness

With `decltype` and `std::is_const` the constness of a variable can be externally detected. **But is it also possible for an object to know its own constness?** Usage should be like:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

struct Test
{
    Test() {}

    bool print() const
    {
       // does not work as is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/9890218/819272
       return std::is_const<decltype(*this)>::value; // <--- what will work??
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    const Test s;

    // external constness test
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_const<decltype(t)>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_const<decltype(s)>::value << "\n";

    // internal constness test
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << t.print() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << s.print() << "\n"; // <--- false??
}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2HfkHT$35) Is this somehow possible?

**MOTIVATION**: I want to be able to detect whether a const member function is invoked on a const object or is coming from a non-const object. The object could e.g. represent a cache and the member a view. If the cache was const, one could presumably use an optimized draw routine, whereas if the underlying data was non-const, the draw routine would need to do periodically check if the data was refreshed.

**NOTE**: the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9890218/819272) asks how to break the build for const objects, but I don't quite understand if the answer to that implies a definite NO for my question. If not, I want to capture the constness in a boolean for further usage.

**EDIT**: as was pointed out @DanielFrey, the constructor is not a good place to test for constness. What about a const member function?

---

**UPDATE**: Thanks everyone for correcting my initially ill-posed question and providing the various parts of the answer (constructors' ill-defined constness, rvaluedness of `this`, the contextual meaning of `const`, the -with hindsight- obvious overload trick that I had overlooked, and the const reference aliasing loophole lurking in the shadows). For me this question was Stackoverflow at its best. I decided to select @JonathanWakely's answer because it showed how to define `Mutable` and `Immutable` classes that strengthen the constness concept to achieve what I want in a foolproof way.

Comment: This seems deeply philosophical somehow.

Comment: @Richard hence the tag "reflection" (for lack of "meditation")

Comment: @rhalbersma  And I saw the C++ tag mixed with reflection and wondered why you were mixing C++ and C# in the one question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have stated, you cannot tell if an object was declared as `const` from within a member function. You can only tell if it's being called in a `const` context, which is not the same.

> **MOTIVATION:** I want to be able to detect whether a const member function is invoked on a const object or is coming from a non-const object. The object could e.g. represent a cache and the member a view. If the cache was const, one could presumably use an optimized draw routine, whereas if the underlying data was non-const, the draw routine would need to do periodically check if the data was refreshed.

You can't tell that reliably.

```
struct A
{
  void draw() { fut = std::async(&A::do_draw, this, false); }
  void draw() const { fut = std::async(&A::do_draw, this, true); }
  void update(Data&);
private:
  void do_draw(bool this_is_const) const;
  mutable std::future<void> fut;
};

A a;
const A& ca = a;
ca.draw();           // object will think it's const, but isn't
Data new_data = ...;
a.update(new_data);  // do_draw() should recheck data, but won't
```

You can model it in the type system, by defining separate mutable and immutable types.

```
struct Base
{
  virtual ~Base();
  virtual void draw() const = 0;
protected:
  void do_draw(bool) const;
};

struct MutableCache : Base
{
  virtual void draw() const { fut = std::async(&Base::do_draw, this, false); }
  void update();
};

struct ImmutableCache : Base
{
  virtual void draw() const { fut = std::async(&Base::do_draw, this, true); }
  // no update function defined, data cannot change!
};
```

Now if a cache is create as an `ImmutableCache` you know it *can't* change, so that replaces your previous idea of a "const" object.  A `MutableCache` can change, so needs to check for refreshed data.

Comment: I don't think `do_draw` being non-`const` works, as you can't invoke it with a `Base const*`, which is what you have in `draw`.

Comment: @Xeo, oops, I got it right in the first example, but got lazy in the second :)

Comment: +1 for the examples. In the first example, I understand that taking const-references to non-const object invokes const members and `draw()` could show an outdated view (@Xeo also made that point in his answer). But why wouldn't `a.draw()` re-check the data?

Comment: Ah, OK, I misread: `ca.draw()` will not re-check the data if that was changed through `a.update()`.

Comment: Yep, the point being that within a member function you can't tell if an object is _really_ const. But with a type that doesn't allow modification you can know for sure that it won't change

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible for constructors (the original question) because of

> #### 12.1 Constructors [class.ctor]
>
> <sup>4</sup> A constructor shall not be `virtual` (10.3) or `static` (9.4). A constructor can be invoked for a `const`, `volatile` or `const volatile` object. A constructor shall not be declared `const`, `volatile`, or `const volatile` (9.3.2). `const` and `volatile` semantics (7.1.6.1) are not applied on an object under construction. They come into effect when the constructor for the most derived object (1.8) ends. A constructor shall not be declared with a ref-qualifier.

For member functions (the current question), you could simply provide both a `const` and a non-`const` overload, forward both to a (private) method that takes the constness as a boolean template parameter.

Comment: +1 Great answer, so I rephrased the question for const member functions (sorry about that).

Comment: Ha!  We brewed up the same workaround.  Compliments on your impressive workaround.  :)

Comment: @DrewDormann: Except that you forgot to forward the constness as a compile-time value to the implementation ;)

Comment: How can you forward that to a template parameter if one of the overloads is non-const?

Comment: @rhalbersma: In the non-const overload, call `private_fun<false>(...)`, and in the const one call `private_fun<true>(...)`. Note that `private_fun` needs to be declared `const` to be called from inside the `const` public function. You can get away with a `const_cast` in case the bool was `true`, though.

Comment: The implementation method must be `const` itself. Of course that means it can not modify non-`mutable` members, but in some use-cases that is good enough. Or you make it a `static` method with an additional template parameter that is deduced from `*this`. (oh, Hi Xeo :)

Comment: Which member function will be called depends on the calling expression---the type of the pointer in `p->function()`, for example, and has nothing to do with the const-ness of the actual object.

Answer (score 4):

> what will work??

Nothing will work.

The object running its constructor is **never `const`**.  It may only be assigned to a `const` variable *after* the constructor has run its course.

It also can't be determined for member functions (non-const member functions included, since `const_cast` may have been used)

Const-ness is a property that exists at **each call site**, not as a property of the function body itself.

> MOTIVATION: I want to be able to detect whether a const member function is invoked on a const object

You can't do that, but you can come close...

```
class C
{
public:
    void func() const
    {
        std::cout << "const!";
        func_impl();
    }
    void func()
    {
        std::cout << "non-const!";
        func_impl();
    }
private:
    void func_impl() const;
};
```

> The object could e.g. represent a cache and the member a view. If the cache was const, one could presumably use an optimized draw routine, whereas if the underlying data was non-const, the draw routine would need to do periodically check if the data was refreshed.

That would be an unreliable usage of `const` because `const` is not a property of the object itself.  It's a property of the current context that the object's being used.

Detecting that it's `const` in the current context doesn't tell you that the object has always been treated in a `const` context.

Comment: +1 but what if the test takes place inside a member function? I will update the question.

Comment: What if the constructor is constexpr?

Comment: @CrazyEddie: Changes nothing, just tells the compiler that object construction can happen as part of a constant expression.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's possible *in that way*, by means of a member value that's set in the constructor, but the object can report its const-ness with member functions:

```
struct Test
{
  bool is_const() const
  {
    return(true);
  }

  bool is_const()
  {
    return(false);
  }
};
```

Comment: +1 silly to have overlooked this as the STL used to do this for `begin()/end()` iterators (whereas now they have gone to `cbegin()/cend()`)

Comment: @rhalbersma: They haven't "gone to", they just *added* those, because it was kind of a pain to get `const_iterator`s specifically from a non-`const` object (there are [some helpers you can use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15234120/500104), to make it better).

Comment: Note that `t.is_const()` doesn't mean changing `t` will be well-defined or undefined, as casts mean people can change the constness at will.

Comment: @GManNickG Good point, but I tend to worry more about Murphy than Machiavelli (free after Herb Sutter)

Answer (score 3):

The type of `this` (and consequently of `*this`) is purely determined by the cv-qualifier of the function and does not change depending on whether the actual object is cv-qualified or not.

`§9.3.2 [class.this] p1`

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of `this` in a member function of a class `X` is `X*`. **If the member function is declared `const`, the type of `this` is `const X*`**, if the member function is declared `volatile`, the type of `this` is `volatile X*`, and if the member function is declared `const volatile`, the type of `this` is `const volatile X*`.

So, you can't see *inside* of a member function whether the object it's invoked on is `const`, but you can make the compiler call different functions depending on `const`ness:

```
struct X{
  void f(){ /* non-const object */ }
  void f() const{ /* const object */ }
};

int main(){
  X x1;
  X const x2;
  x1.f(); // calls non-const 'f'
  x2.f(); // calls const 'f'

  // but beware:
  X const& rx = x1;
  rx.f(); // calls const 'f', because the "object" it's invoked on is const
}
```

Beware of the limitation laid out in the snippet, though.

Comment: +1 for the Standard quote and the example. I also need a different return type (as does `begin()` with `iterator` vs `const_iterator`), but that works as well.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible because it's possible for a particular value to be simultaneously viewed as `const` and not `const`.  Consider

```
MyType t = ...;
MyType& nonConstRef = t;
const MyType& constRef = t;
```

At this point `t` has both a `const` and a non-const reference.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting constness within an object isn't possible, but you state that your motivation is…

> “ I want to be able to detect whether a const member function is invoked on a const object or is coming from a non-const object.”

Well that’s easy, just provide a non-`const` overload.

The overloads can defer to a common implementation, e.g. as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    template< class CvTest >
    static void print( CvTest& o )
    {
        cout << boolalpha;
        cout << "> object says: Hey, const = " << std::is_const<CvTest>::value << "!" << endl;
    }

public:
    bool print()        { return (print( *this ), false); }
    bool print() const  { return (print( *this ), true); }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    const Test s;

    cout << "External constness test:" << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << is_const<decltype(t)>::value << "\n";
    cout << boolalpha << is_const<decltype(s)>::value << "\n";

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Internal constness test:" << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << t.print() << "\n";
    cout << boolalpha << s.print() << "\n";
}
```

Results:

```
External constness test:
false
true

Internal constness test:
> object says: Hey, const = false!
false
> object says: Hey, const = true!
true
```