# Is there a way to detect construction of a const qualified object?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, constants, c++14

Assuming two declarations:

```
const type x;  // case a
type y;        // case b
```

is it possible to detect case "a" or "b" in `type`'s constructor so that I can execute different operations?

From the standard §12.1/3 we have that:

> A constructor can be invoked for a const, volatile or const volatile object. **const and volatile semantics (7.1.6.1) are not applied on an object under construction**. They come into effect when the constructor for the most derived object (1.8) ends.

therefore [`this` behaves like expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c928c9118d7bd20) by never being `const`-qualified at construction (otherwise how could you edit member objects in the body?). So, it seems it's not possible to use type traits on `this`.

A **use case** for this would be the following: assuming you are working with an underlying C API that describe specific objects (in a much wider sense), taking *hints* on their future use along the lines of:

- `STATIC` = will not be modified
- `DYNAMIC` = can be modified

one could create a wrapper around those C objects and give a `STATIC` hint on a `const` construction, and a `DYNAMIC` hint on a non const construction. Of course `const_cast` exists and could mess things up, but I'm assuming *sane* coding here :P.

Am I missing something (considering also C++11 and [C++14](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/N3936.pdf))?

Comment: Imagine this were possible and I'd define `const T make();`, and then say `T nonconst = make();`. Boom?

Comment: @KerrekSB, well, the copy constructor of `nonconst` would detect its non `const`ness and read the hint of the other object (from `make`) and construct a `DYNAMIC`ally hinted object?

Comment: Well, if anything, it'd be really weird and unexpected to make a copy of something and then end up with something different... I think you'd have a hard time arguing that such a thing should be possible.

Comment: @KerrekSB, why? The only thing that you should think is: is the object I'm considering `const`? No? Then it will be `STATIC`ally hinted. Yes? Then it will be `DYNAMIC`ally hinted. Also this *hints* would be implementation details, not part of the interface, so the user shouldn't worry about them anyway.

Comment: There was a related question some weeks (months?) ago. I suggested making `type` noncopyable and nonmovable, and provide a `create` function, so that you can only bind references to the objects. You'd end up with `auto const& x = make_const();` and `auto&& y = make_nonconst();` but you could still `auto const& x = make_nonconst();` which is unfortunate. Another way could be to use the declared `x` in the `make` function, e.g. `const type x = make(x);` and deduce the const-ness of `x` inside `make` (error-prone as well).

Comment: @dyp Yep, seems like the only possibility to me.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15279508/819272

Comment: @dyp `const type x = make(x);`... is that really valid/well defined?? What exactly does that do?

Comment: @SchighSchagh My intention was to write something like `template<class T> T make(T&) { return T(std::is_const<T>{}); }`, where no access to `x` takes place (no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion etc.). I think just *forming* a reference at this point is still defined behaviour, it would only be used to deduce the type of the variable being initialized. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d1df533b9e0a2dd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont really know if its worth the struggle and this solution is for sure not perfect as we have to use a helper class `Object<T>`, but atleast it works very similiar to your requested behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using Object = typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>::value, typename T::const_type, typename T::type>::type;

template<bool IsConst>
struct FooHelper;

struct Foo
{
    typedef FooHelper<false> type;
    typedef const FooHelper<true> const_type;

protected:

    Foo(bool isConst)
    {
        if (isConst)
            std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "non-const" << std::endl;
    }

};

template<>
struct FooHelper<false> : public Foo
{
    FooHelper() : Foo(false) {}
};

template<>
struct FooHelper<true> : public Foo
{
    FooHelper() : Foo(true) {}
};

int main()
{
    Object<Foo> obj;
    Object<const Foo> cobj;
}
```